# Survey123 Connect Publishing Error 400: Create Table failed

Tags: error, publishing, arcgis-survey123-connect

I am receiving the following error when attempting to publish a new survey. I don't know what to fix, as the xlsx file looks fine.

[image]

Here is a link to the file:
[XLSX Form](https://ttard-ccbo.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/27265967bc114049b09e6a7568ae7234/data)